# Image with rounded corners in android

Tags: android

i just wanna display one image with rounded corners(not on background view)in android.How could i do this?Help me..Thanks
Regards,
Sudhakar.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you have a normal image and you want to display it with rounded corners ?

What I would do is to create a nine-patch image with your corners (lots of resources on how to do that : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html). Beside the black corners (or whatever the color), make everything else transparent.

Then you can draw that image on top of your picture with the right layout.